# Json to kotlin data classes

Tags: java, android, json, gson, kotlin

Is there existing service for generating kotlin data classes from json model in the way how it works on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ site? My new project has over complicated API responses, so it would save me time.

Comment: The plugin for android studio auto converts java to kotlin, so you could generate the java classes and then on the IDE convert the java classes to kotlin.

Comment: @Logain Thanks, it's really good idea I missed this option

Comment: The plugin for Eclipse also can convert java to kotlin

Comment: try www.json2kotlin.com if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator

Comment: [JSON To Kotlin Class ​(JsonToKotlinClass)​](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a plugin for Android Studio and Intellij Idea called **JsonToKotlinClass**.

You can convert `json` into kotlin's `data class` with it: https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass

[image: A AndroidStudio plugin for Converting json string into kotlin data class]

Comment: Problem is, it doesn't work when the the Json string is an Array

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa You can raise an issue here: https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass/issues

Comment: For any future visitors, the actual plugin name is JsonToKotlinClass

Comment: It is perfect way to concert a json to pojo for kotlin !

Comment: For online json to data class generator use this: https://json2kt.com/ I think it's cool :)

Comment: [JSON To Kotlin Class ​(JsonToKotlinClass)​](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-)